# Visual Basic: Stopping a background thread from the main thread possible?

Tags: vba, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, thread-safety

I am writing a program (in Microsoft Visual Basic) to control a remote instrument (an XY axis microscope stage). As an example, the user must initially calibrate the stage by clicking a GUI button. It takes some time to accomplish the calibration process and I do not want to freeze the main GUI, so I execute the call on a background thread, as follows:

```
Call New Thread(AddressOf CALIBRATE_STAGE) With {.IsBackground = True}.Start()
```

So that works well, but we can imagine that for some reason, the user might need to halt the calibration before it is completed. The halt command must originate from a button on the GUI but it cannot be run from the main thread, or a HUGE instability results. (Basically, a program crash, probably because the sub thread was incorrectly managed. The only fix is to completely reboot the computer.)

I think what I need to do is something like this pseudo-code:

1. Press HALT button on GUI
2. Execute the STAGE HALT command on the same sub-thread where the CALIBRATE_STAGE command was launched
3. Once the stage is halted, properly abort the sub thread

Trouble is, I do not know how to do acquire the specific sub-thread on which CALIBRATE_STAGE is running. I do know its ThreadID, but given that integer, how do I launch a new process on that thread? Does anyone have some ideas?

Or maybe someone knows this idea of mine will not work and has a better solution?

Comment: Please clarify in your text: Do you _fear_ that your program will crash when issuing the close command from the main thread or did you try it and it crashed? One hint I can give you right now is a look at "interprocess communicaton in VBA" or maybe "sending signals to other threads", something like that. Please add a list of things you tried to solve the problem on your own, so that others do not do duplicate work.

Comment: Hi Andreas -- The program DEFINITELY crashes! Thanks for the suggestion on interprocess communication searches, I will look.